# Progressively draw dashed line in CSS3 - animation

Tags: html, css, animation

I found the following code to progressively draw a line with css3 animation and the svg canvas. The only problem is I'd like the line to be dashed but I'm not sure how I can modify it to do so, changing the stroke-dasharray doesn't seem to do anything. Thanks!

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400px" height="300px">
  <style type="text/css">
    path {
      animation-name:animateDash;
      animation-duration:5s;
      animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    }
    @keyframes animateDash {
      from{stroke-dasharray:0,2305}
      to  {stroke-dasharray:2305,0}
    } 
  </style>
  <path d="m 7.1428565,220.9336 c 0,0 13.6660115,54.75386 218.5714335,51.42857 C 430.61971,269.03688 478.47682,99.194335 206.69537,110.78149 -65.086093,122.36866 45.497658,213.22607 210.28635,207.29759 375.07503,201.3691 429.75297,97.468925 207.14285,82.362175 -15.467268,67.255425 64.868608,160.66909 210,153.79075 c 145.13139,-6.87834 137.69998,-93.087405 11.42857,-99.999995 -126.271412,-6.9126 -150.382292,28.03248 -24.28571,35.71428 126.09659,7.6818 72.6601,-44.83727 -5.71429,-84.2857095"
    stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="0,2305"/>
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G4b6b/

Comment: i see nothing on your jsfiddle. Is it actually supports svg? also your css included into solid file but not in css field. Is it fine too?

Comment: yeh I put the css in the css field and it stopped working, try testing in firefox

Comment: i think it's jsfiddle problem kinda. actually such code better to get in CDATA brace. Sorry. But can't test it on FF. Chrome says "no such attributes", but i think it's chrome trouble

Comment: Not able to archive your goal, but it's still interesting to share: http://jsfiddle.net/G4b6b/1/ Hope this inspire your somehow.

Comment: nearly passerby, what did you change?

Comment: @user1937021 Notably the `to` part in `keyframes`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an article that might help you: [SVG Stroke Proprieties](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_stroking.asp). The updated fiddle is [Fiddle Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/G4b6b/53/). The stroke-dasharray propriety is what you want to play with to achieve the result you wish.

```
@keyframes animateDash {
  from{stroke-dasharray:10,10}
  to  {stroke-dasharray:15,15}
}
```

If that is not what you want, and you need more help, give me more detailes.

Hope it helps.

```css
    path {
      animation-name:animateDash;
      animation-duration:3s;
      animation-iteration-count:3;
    }
    @keyframes animateDash {
      from{stroke-dasharray:10,10}
      to  {stroke-dasharray:15,15}
    }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400px" height="300px">
  <style type="text/css">
  </style>
  <path d="m 7.1428565,220.9336 c 0,0 13.6660115,54.75386 218.5714335,51.42857 C 430.61971,269.03688 478.47682,99.194335 206.69537,110.78149 -65.086093,122.36866 45.497658,213.22607 210.28635,207.29759 375.07503,201.3691 429.75297,97.468925 207.14285,82.362175 -15.467268,67.255425 64.868608,160.66909 210,153.79075 c 145.13139,-6.87834 137.69998,-93.087405 11.42857,-99.999995 -126.271412,-6.9126 -150.382292,28.03248 -24.28571,35.71428 126.09659,7.6818 72.6601,-44.83727 -5.71429,-84.2857095"
    stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-dasharray="10,10" d="M5 60 l215 0"/>
</svg>
```